# Enable secure admin by script

Tags: configuration, scripting, glassfish

Does anyone know how to enable secure admin from script? The problem is that the command `asadmin enable-secure-admin` requires authentication from the commandline but I would like to do that by script. I already tried to save the user/password in a temporary file and then passing it in by `asadmin enable-secure-admin < auth.txt` but unfortunately I get an authentication failure for user `null`

Has anyone already done this?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the solution by myself I only had to read the command help ;-)

```
Usage: asadmin [-H|--host <host(default:localhost)>]
[-p|--port <port(default:4848)>] [-u|--user <user(default:admin)>]
[-W|--passwordfile <passwordfile>]
[-t|--terse[=<terse(default:false)>]]
[-s|--secure[=<secure(default:false)>]]
[-e|--echo[=<echo(default:false)>]]
[-I|--interactive[=<interactive(default:true)>]]
[-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>] 
[--detach(default:false)] 
[--notify(default:false)] [subcommand [options] [operands]]
```

Here's what I did: `asadmin --interactive=false --user admin --passwordfile /path/to/passwordfile enable-secure-admin`